# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown in Table Data Cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

My view shows a table of products that are returned in a search, as well as their respective details, the vendors who sell those products, and their associated price. What I'm trying to do is to put vendors and price in a dropdown, rather than have two data cell that have 5+ vendors and prices distorting the table row height. Is this possible? What would be the best approach? I've looked at using a list, but not sure how to get both price and vendors in a dropdown together that way. I'm currently using a table within a table (table inception), but please let me know if you think there's a better way. Here's my current view:

```
<table>  
<tr class="search-table">  
  <td>Product</td>
  <td>Details</td>
  <td>Brand</td>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Vendors</td>
</tr>

<% @search_res.each do |item| %>

 <tr class="search-table"> 
  <td><%= item.product %></td>
   <td><%= item.details %></td>
   <td><%= item.brand %></td>
   <td><%= item.id %></td>
    <td>
     <table>

      <tr>
        <% item.vendors.each do |vendor| %>
        <td><%= vendor.name %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <% item.inventory_items.each do |product| %>
        <td><%= product.price %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some errors in markup worthy to mentioned before all:

1. your css class "search-table" possibly is not assumed to be applied to a table's row:
   `<tr class="search-table">`
2. Header row semantically better to wrap in "thead" tag and columns in the row markup as "th" tag: `<thead> <tr class="search-table">  <th>Product</th>  <th>Details</th>  <th>Brand</th>  <th>ID</th>  <th>Vendors</th>  </tr><thead>`
3. on the matter of question, I think that using Bootstrap framework and dropdowns wouldn't be convienient. IMHO collapsible elements would make the trick of show of some extra info.
   Just wrap collpsible divs into table's cell, it will look something like that:
   http://jsfiddle.net/aizekAzimov/9LHw2/

hope it'll help

Comment: Right you are, forgot to mention that my code was probably not all that pretty. Thanks for the tips. I will look at collapsable elements.